# Insert characters between strings in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a string which contains

> A F C A D A B A F G H A B C D A E A X B

I want to append a tag before and after A B like [A B]

> A F C A D [A B] A F G H [A B] C D A E [A X B] J H A

Working in vb.net windows form

Comment: I got the answer and marked it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely not the most elegant solution but I believe it works:

```
String strInput = "A F C A D A B A F G H A B C D A E A X B J H A A C D A E X B";
StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbTemp = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Char ch in strInput)
{
    if (ch.Equals('A'))
    {
        if (sbTemp.Length > 0)
        {
            sbOutput.Append(sbTemp.ToString());
            sbTemp = new StringBuilder().Append(ch);
        }
        else
        {
            sbTemp.Append(ch);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (sbTemp.Length > 0)
        {
            sbTemp.Append(ch);
            if (ch.Equals('B'))
            {
                sbOutput.Append(String.Format("[{0}]", sbTemp.ToString()));
                sbTemp = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sbOutput.Append(ch);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from other answers?

Comment: There will be some additional characters between A and B, IT is a dynamic generation example A F C A D [A B] A F G H [A B] C D A E [A X B] J H A, here X is generated dynamically, dosen't know which character will come in between A and B

Comment: @dotNET - it is not. In fact all answers are now invalid as the question is changed!

Comment: @mcbalaji - Yes I see that the question is changed now. I am not very conversant in VB.NET. If I share a solution in C# will it suffice?

Comment: sure i ll change to vb.net

Comment: @mcbalaji - I have updated my answer, have a look. Also please mark it as Answer if it resolves your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.Replace("A B", "[A B]")
```

Comment: How is this different from other answers?

Comment: well there were no answers at the time I have posted this, and I noticed the question was changed.

Answer (score 0):

A hard coded replace of "A B" to "[A B]" won't work if you have "A X B", So i would suggest a possible solution, which is regex:

Try these two patterns:

```
Dim pattern1 as string = @"(A)[^A]*(?=B)"
Dim str as string = Regex.Replace(inputString, pattern1, "[\1"); // make `A` to `[A` followed by a `B`

Dim pattern2 as string = @"(?<=A)[^A]*(B)"
str = Regex.Replace(str, pattern1, "\1]"); // make `B` to `B]` // make `B` to `B]` preceded by `A`

Debug.Print(str);
```

Hope it helps!